# Which even bases do self "dividing" numbers exist?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Define a self dividing number in base n to be a number n digits long such that

- The digits $0-9$(depending on base) is used exactly once
- The first h digits are divisible by h,

for example in decimal we have

$3,816,547,290$

$(3/1=1),(38/2=19),(381/3=127),(3,816/4=954),...(3,816,547,290/10=381,654,729)$

other examples

$(10)_2,(1230)_4,(143250)_6$

Which is the least even base n that does not have this property?

Comment: Doesn't $(10)_2$ have this property in binary? 1 is divisible by 1 and $(10)_2$ is 2 which is divisible by 2.

Comment: Consider such a number in base $b$. Note that $0$ must occur last, as per the $b$ divisibility test. The non-zero digits must sum to a multiple of $b - 1$, as per the $b - 1$ divisibility test. This only happens for even $b$, so such numbers cannot occur for odd $b$.

Comment: @CarlMummert yes sorry i meant greater then 2

Comment: It seems $(1230)_4$ has the property in base 4.  1 is divisible by 1, $(12)_4 = 6$ is divisible by 2, $(123)_4 = 27$ is divisible by 3, and $(1230)_4$ is divisible by 4.  What other bases have you tried?

Comment: @CarlMummert your right, i made an error in my code and should have tried by hand

Comment: FYI, as shown in [10 digit number where first n digits are divisible by n](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/10-digit-number-where-first-n-digits-are-divisible-by-n), your example of $3,816,547,290$ is the only solution for base $10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base $8$, there is $(32541670)_8$, so every even base up to $10$ is possible.  A brute force search finds no solution in base $12$.

There is, by the way, a solution in base $14$:
$$
(9\text{C}3\text{A}5476\text{B}812\text{D}0)_{14},
$$
where A,B,C,D represent the digits $10,11,12,13$, but none for bases $16,18,20$ or $22$.

Comment: what code did you use to do the brute force search?

Comment: An $11$-line recursive Python function.